# Inertia Tensor Relative to Center of Mass vs Inertia Tensor in Body Coordinates

Tags: rotation, matrix

If I have the inertia tensor relative to the center of mass, is that the same as the inertia tensor in body coordinates?
If no, can you please explain the difference and how do I numerically calculate the inertia tensor in body coordinates using the inertia tensor relative to the center of mass?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same, just as long as the point mass vectors are calculated using the offset from the center of mass and there is rotation or no scaling applied.

The inertia tensor is fixed in body (local) space. It only needs to be calculated once and stored.